# Signed vs Unsigned numbers 0xFFFFFFFF ambiguity?

Tags: c#, c++, binary

**As you can see here I have an unsigned variable and a signed one both with the same binary values but different decimal results.**

```
 uint unsigned = 0xFFFFFFFF; // 4,294,967,295
 int signed = 0xFFFFFFFF;    // -1
```

I am really confused! How does the machine make the difference between signed and unsigned , after all those are 32/64 bits all turned on. Is there a **CPU** **flag** that is used exactly for this? How does the CPU know the difference between a **unsigned** and a **signed** number? Trying to understand the concept for hours!

**Or... another example...let's take 4 bits:**

```
// 1 1 0 1  <--- -3
// 0 0 1 0  <---  2
```

If we subtract 2 from -3 the result will be:

```
// 1 0 0 1  <--- -1 or 9???
```

The cpu will yield that result, but how does my application know that it is a -1 or a 9? It is known at compile time the expected result type?

**another example...**

```
    int negative = -1;
    Console.WriteLine(negative.ToString("X")); //output FFFFFFFF
    uint positive = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    Console.WriteLine(positive.ToString("X")); //output FFFFFFFF
```

> later edit :

I messed up a little more with this stuff and I think I got it and please correct me if I am wrong: 
We have the following example:

```
    sbyte positive = 15;                          //0xF   ( 0000 1111)
    sbyte negative = unchecked((sbyte)-positive); //0xF01;( 1111 0001)

    sbyte anotherPositive = 7;                    //0x7   ( 0000 0111)

    sbyte result = (sbyte)(negative + anotherPositive); 
//The cpu will add the numbers 1111 0001                                                              
//                             0000 0111                                                     
//                             1111 1000   
// (Addition result is 248  but our variable is 
//SIGNED and we have the sign bit ON(1) so the the value will be interpreted as -8)
```

Comment: I dont think it's a matter of how CPU does, it's more of how your program will interpret it. Also, note that `uint unsigned` doesn't make sense. `unsigned int` might be waht you mean.

Comment: Read about it all: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signedness

Comment: You spammed tags for very different languages. Pick one!

Comment: The CPU doesn't tell a difference in the *data* itself. The compiler will use signed or unsigned instructions (if that's even neccessary) depending on context.

Comment: So the notion is only at compiler level. That makes sense.

Comment: *"Is there a CPU flag that is used exactly for this ?"* - in some CPUs yes, there is a sign bit and corresponding status flag. It's not CPU, it's you should take care to deal with signed/unsigned values properly. CPU is blind and do exactly what compiled code say. Compiler is a bit smarter, but may do not what you think it will do and you will end up with bug.

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot because it is related and since I have a 5 tag limit why not add them? Let's stay on topic.

Comment: Ok @Sinatr that makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: @Glorin *The CPU doesn't tell a difference in the data itself.* There are specific operators for signed and unsigned comparison.. For example for the `>` operator, the various Jump instructions of intel are based on the "signess": http://unixwiz.net/techtips/x86-jumps.html

Comment: @xanatos hence the rest of the comment. Bits are bits to the CPU, its all about the *instructions*.

Comment: It's extremely important that the CPU knows the difference between signed and unsigned when it is doing calculations! The JIT compiler will compile the IL code into specific CPU instructions appropriate for the kind of calculations being done. The CPU doesn't intrinsically know the difference between signed/unsigned, but it is told what signed or unsigned instructions to use.

Comment: @VeronikaPrüssels:  There are (often) different opcodes for different types, (eg floating point/16-bit int/32-bit int) so at that level the CPU cares.  In the case of signed/unsigned, there is likely to be a difference between the shift-right opcode.

Comment: 1) I think you meant me. 2) Just because there can be 5 tags added does not mean you have to use them all. On the contrary, you should use only the tags relevant and not making your question too broad. If you don't know why two tags should be removed, read the standards/specifications of the languages. Or just leave the tag for the language you use.

Comment: Are you asking about how the CPU interprets signed vs. unsigned?  In many platforms, the highest bit is used as the "sign" bit for signed integers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I am really confused! How does the machine make the difference between at low level , after all those are 32 bits all turned on.

Machine doesn't; the compiler does. It is the compiler that knows the type of `signed` and `unsigned` variables (ignoring for a moment the fact that both `signed` and `unsigned` are keywords in C and C++). Therefore, the compiler knows what instructions to generate and what functions to call based on these types.

The distinction between the types is made at compile time, changing the interpretation of possibly identical raw data based on its compile-time type.

Consider an example of printing the value of a variable. When you write

```
cout << mySignedVariable << " " << myUnsignedVariable << endl;
```

the compiler sees two overloads of [`<<` operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) being applied:

- The first `<<` makes a call to `ostream& operator<< (int val);`
- The second `<<` makes a call to `ostream& operator<< (unsigned int val);`

Once the code reaches the proper operator implementation, you are done: the code generated for the specific overload has the information on how to handle the signed or unsigned value "baked into" its machine code. The implementation that takes an `int` uses signed machine instructions for comparisons, divisions, multiplications, etc. while the unsigned implementation uses different instructions, producing the desired results.

Comment: Not sure but I have some cloudy memory about an architecture which indeed knew the type of an object. It might have been the i432. Also for dynamically typed, they also have to know the properties of an object (in the wider sense). Or just take LLVM which can be seen as a software-CPU (one could very well design a hardware interpreter (aka "normal" CPU) for that bytecode).

Comment: So there are different instructions? hmmm

Comment: @Olaf Wow, did you actually work with i432? I read about the architecture back in late eighties, expecting it to take over the world. The funny thing was, by the time I read about it the project has already been discontinued by Intel. I didn't know about it,because the book I was reading in 1988 was a translation of 1983 book, published in 1987.

Comment: @MihailGeorgescu This depends on the architecture: it could be either different instructions, or different arrangements of the same instructions on simpler architectures.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: No, I worked with Apple ][, C64 Amstrad CPC and Atari-ST back then. I just read about such "dream-systems" in some computer magazines. Didn't understand half of the subject, that's why I just have some very nebulous memories. Might as well have been some other design; in the 80ies there was quite some interesting hardware. Funny, because they always were low on transistors, while nowadays I have the impression Intel&Co don't know where to spend some spare mio transistors.

Comment: Hmm, an FPGA implementation of LLVM could be fun.

Comment: Sir I updated the question , I think I got it, I wrote and example after "later edit" , please correct me if I am wrong but on paper this works , just trying to figure it out how the language interprets the result. Thank you!

Comment: @MihailGeorgescu The things that you describe in the edit work the way you expect. If you are looking to understand why this works like that, try playing with the concept in decimal: add 99 to any two digit decimal number, and drop hundreds. Then add 98, 97, 96, each time dropping hundreds. Note the pattern. Do you see how adding a positive number (100-x) behaves the same as adding a negative number x after you drop hundreds? The same exact thing happens with binary when you use two's complement representation of negative integers.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight thank you again sir! I salute you!

Answer (score 1):

It's the job of the language's *type system* to interpret what it sees.

All the CPU really sees is a bunch of zeros and ones.

Interestingly, two's complement arithmetic can use the same instructions as unsigned arithmetic. One's complement arithmetic requires an annoying *complementing subtractor*.

Comment: How about a bytecode interpreter? That would actually be an emulated CPU which very well has to know about types at a certain degree. It becomes worse for dynamically typed languages like Python.

Answer (score 0):

the computer doesn't care, as far as its concerned they are both the same, its the compiler and language structure running on the computer that decides how to interpret and handle the bit array and they know if its a uint, int, double, single, unicode char etc.

that's why managed memory is so important, if your program writes a uint to a memory address and another program reads it an a char then you get all sorts of strange behaviour, this can been seen when you open a binary file in notepad

Comment: For bytecode, the interpreter is actually the "computer" (better: the CPU). Thus, it very well might have to care.

Comment: i used the term computer to avoid the sort of terminology argument you are trying to start,, a CPU in its most basic form is a Collection of logical gates that can be be linked to a memory store in such a way that the memory can select which gates are used, and all a logic gate does is take 2 inputs perform there function and send out the output , so the CPU doesn't care that running operation 24 on values FF and BC means to write BC in the memory slot with address FF, it just feeds FF and BC in the the set of gates designated as 24.

Comment: its one level up in the compiler where meaningful instruction are changed into operations that the CPU can slavishly follow with no understanding of what is happening, an interpreter is just a compiler than compiles compile on the fly then feeds them into the CPU rather than creating a stored list of reusable instruction in a executable file

Comment: Just in case you mean me (properly address a comment!): Can you provide a link where a CPU has to be represented by a specific technique? There are paper-CPUs, relais, etc. Modern CPUs are normally tested using FPGAs with the CPU defined by a HDL or by emulator software, etc. Using the even less defined term "computer" does not help, but makes things just worse. Your definition of a CPU is way too restrictive. And logic gates can have more or less than two inputs and more than one output. I learned the basics decades ago, thanks, I'm very sure I know them better than you state here.

Comment: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/central-processing-unit
central processing unit
noun
1.
the part of a computer that performs logical and arithmetical operations on the data as specified in the instructions CPU

Comment: This is a recursive definition and does not state how the CPU nor the computer are implemented. Just widen your horizon from what you have learned from school or a dictionary. (honestly: not meant offensive; I just don't know how to wrap it in metaphoric cotton balls.)

Comment: you can emulate the function of a CPU to test it however the emulation of a thing is not the thing itself just something that reproduces the output generated by the thing in a reliable manor, and you can represent one on paper but then its your brain following the representation that is performing the emulation

Comment: You are aware there are microcode-CPUs which execute the actual instructions using some internal program code? Classical CPUs like 68000, Z80 or 8086 until 80386 (not sure about 486) did this for all instructions. Modern x86 actually generates internal RISC-code form the x86 instruction set and executes more complex x86 instructions with RISC-ops microcode. What about emulators like qemu where actual programs are excuted on an emulated CPU only? Simulation != emulation.

Comment: Microcode is "a technique that imposes an interpreter between the hardware and the architectural level of a computer" ego a Microcode CPU, is a CPU with a Microcode interpreter interfaced with it, this allows better performance than a CPU using older style interpreters

Comment: So you claim a CPU is actually just a sequencer, nothing else? Sorry, you are wrong. The microcode interpreter is part of the CPU already. As is the register-bank, renamer, etc.